# Python: How do I change a value in column A if another value in column B repeats itself?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, glob

I have many excel files with the same columns in one folder. I need to browse each file and compare which values of the column "User Number" of one file are the same as the other file. And then manipulate another column named "Date" based on that. For exemple:

```
A2018_02_01 file has:          

User_Number    Date            
18732A         2017-06-22
27192B         2017-08-06    
23872Z         2017-08-06    
82716A         2017-09-18      
77629B         2017-09-12      

A2018_02_02 file has:

User_Number    Date
18732A        2017-06-22
27192B        2017-08-06
54321R         2017-12-11
23872Z        2017-11-04
18732A        2017-06-25
```

So in this case I want the program to check for matches of User Number values and then, if the date - linked to this number - of one file is different from the date of the other file, I want to change both dates to be the oldest date.

In this case I would have:

```
A2018_02_01 file has:          

User_Number    Date            
18732A         2017-06-22      
27192B         2017-08-06      
23872Z         2017-08-06      
82716A         2017-09-18      
77629B         2017-09-12      

A2018_02_02 file has:

User_Number    Date
18732A         2017-06-22
27192B         2017-08-06
54321R         2017-12-11
23872Z         2017-08-06
18732A         2017-06-22
```

I appended all the files:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

path=r'C/.../files'
files = os.listdir(path)
df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx"):
    data = pd.read_excel(f,header=2)
    df=df.append(data)
    df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], errors='coerce')
```

The logic doesn't work like javascript logic, so I'm not sure how to do the condition. I've tried:

```
df_number = df["User Number"]
for number in df[df_number.duplicated()]:
    number.df["Date"]number.df["Date"].min()
```

And other methods, but nothing works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you sure your code is complete? last line of code seems like nonsense without '='

Comment: it's not completed, I'm still trying to understand the logic. I don't know how to  change the date based on the value of number (and at the same time compare both dates to see which one is the oldest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is to create a master mapper with all the min dates:

```
master=pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('User_Number').min()
```

and then join each dataframe to the master to find the adjusted date:

```
df1.join(master,rsuffix='_adj',on='User_Number')[['User_Number', 'Date_adj']])
df2.join(master,rsuffix='_adj',on='User_Number')[['User_Number', 'Date_adj']])
```

Output:

```
    User_Number    Date_adj
0      18732A  2017-06-22
1      27192B  2017-08-06
2      23872Z  2017-08-06
3      82716A  2017-09-18
4      77629B  2017-09-12

   User_Number    Date_adj
0      18732A  2017-06-22
1      27192B  2017-08-06
2      54321R  2017-12-11
3      23872Z  2017-08-06
4      18732A  2017-06-22
```

Adapting it to your code:

```
list_of_df = []
for f in glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx"):
    data = pd.read_excel(f,header=2)
    list_of_df.append(data)

df = pd.concat(list_of_df)
df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], errors='coerce')
master=df.groupby('User_Number').min()

for aux_df in list_of_df:
   aux_df['Date'] = aux_df.join(master,rsuffix='_adj',on='User_Number')[['Date_adj']])
```

Comment: I did it :) just another question: in this case, you compared 2 dataframes. How can I do it with an unknown number of dataframes? I have a file with x dataframes.

Comment: when you say that I compare, I guess you refer to the concatenation of two dataframes. If you have a list of dataframes, `pd.concat(list_of_df)` will create one from all your dfs

Comment: <code> for f in glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx"):
    data = pd.read_excel(f,header=2)    
    df=df.concat(data) .groupby('User_Number').min()
data.join(master,rsuffix='_adj',on='User_Number')[['User_Number', 'Date_adj']]) <code>but when I call data, I get an error saying that data is not defined

Comment: I updated my answer to better fit your original code

Comment: Oh ok, I got it. Thanks (: